# Como eliminar un carácter de una lista de manera permanente en Python, incluso si dicho carácter de repite mas de una vez

Tags: python, lista

estoy construyendo un programa en Python que pida una cadena de caracteres por teclado, a lo que el programa deberá responder si esa cadena es palíndroma (se lee igual al derecho que al revés) o no lo es.

El código que muestro a continuación funciona correctamente en el caso de ser una palabra solo. Mi problema viene cuando el usuario introduce una frase, la cual al convertirla a lista toma el espacio como carácter.

He pensado en si existía un método de listas hecho para eso, para eliminar los espacios o cualquier carácter de una lista independientemente si aparece una o mas veces pero no he encontrado nada. Tal vez me puedan ayudar a encontrarlo o hacer desaparecer los espacios de otra manera. Gracias de antemano

```
#CODIGO DEL PROGRAMA ACTUAL

print("DESCUBRA SI UNA PALABRA ES PALINDROMA")

palabra=str(input("Introduzca una palabra: "))

milista=list(palabra)
milista1=list(palabra)
milista1.reverse()

if milista==milista1:
    print("Es palindroma")
else:
    print("No es palindroma")
```

Comment: `palabra.replace(" ", "")`

Comment: `''.join(palabra.split())` elimina multiples blancos, tabulaciones, `\r`, `\n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para probar si la palabra/frase es palindroma, es conveniente definir una función:

```
def es_palindromo(palabra):
    palabra = ''.join(palabra.lower().split())
    inversa = palabra[::-1]
    return palabra == inversa
```

Para comparar primero reducimos todo a minúsculas, para que "A" y "a" sean iguales, y luego separamos las palabras con `split` para eliminar todos los espacios, tabuladores y caracteres similares.

Finalmente, con `join` tomamos la lista de palabras y las juntamos todas, sin espacios entremedio.

Así, con una frase como

```
A cavar     a Caravaca
```

obtenemos `palabra` con valor

```
acavaracaravaca
```

Para invertir usamos rebanada de lista, copiando la palabra entera de atrás hacia adelante (de derecha a izquierda). Eso se logra poniendo como tercer argumento -1, en

```
inversa = palabra[::-1]
```

Entonces basta comparar ambas cadenas; si son iguales, es palindroma.

**Demo**

```
tests = ["A cavar     a Caravaca",
         "A Colima  va    mi loca",
         "Aji traga         la lagartija",
         "A la    torre derrotala",
         "Ali tomo    tila",
         "La mona jacinta   se ha puesto una cinta",
         "Alli    ves Sevilla",
         "Alli si    Maria avisa y asi va a ir a mi silla"]

for test in tests:
    print(f'"{test}"', end=" ")
    if es_palindromo(test):
        print("es palindroma")
    else:
        print("no es palindroma")
```

produce:

```
"A cavar     a Caravaca" es palindroma
"A Colima  va    mi loca" es palindroma
"Aji traga         la lagartija" es palindroma
"A la    torre derrotala" es palindroma
"Ali tomo    tila" es palindroma
"La mona jacinta   se ha puesto una cinta" no es palindroma
"Alli    ves Sevilla" es palindroma
"Alli si    Maria avisa y asi va a ir a mi silla" es palindroma
```